# Struct inside Protocol

Tags: swift, struct, protocols

I have a protocol which has a struct as a property:

```
struct Dimensions {
    var width: CGFloat
    var height: CGFloat
}

Protocol ShapeType {
    var dimensions: Dimensions {get set}
}
```

Now I have a class which is a subclass of `SKShapeNode` :

```
class Shapes: SKShapeNode, ShapeType {
    var dimensions: Dimensions

    override init {       // Error
        super.init()

        dimensions = Dimensions(width: 40, height: 40)
    }
}
```

I get this error:

```
Property 'self.dimensions' not initialized at super.init call
```

What is the proper way to inisialzie the struct inside the class?

Comment: So many problems in your code. Protocol s/b protocol. Need parens after init.  Do you actually have code that can get the error message you quote?  Try posting that.

Comment: There is a comment in the code where the error appears. Would you clarify more on what kinds of problems I have in my code?

Comment: @Abdou023 He was quite clear. `Protocol` is incorrect, as it's not the same thing as `protocol`. In `Shapes`, you're missing `()` after `override init`.  You're also subclassing `SKShapeNode` in an incomplete way, as you have to implement its `required init(coder:)`. Please post code that will actually build, or learn how to fix the other problems in your code if you don't know why they're wrong, because as it stands we're left to fix several problems in your code that aren't related to your original question.

Comment: I appreciate your help guys, but I asked a specific question and provided a specific error, you got distracted by irrelevant issues ( the guy who answered me certainly didn't)
The problems you mentioned are just typos here on this website because I quickly wrote that code here to focus on the problem I' having instead of copy/pasting my entire class which would've  been meaningless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to initialize self.dimensions before you call the super.init() method in your Shapes class initializer

```
init(dimensions: Dimensions) {
    self.dimensions = dimensions
    super.init()
}
```

Comment: You are assigning a property (self.dimensions) to a type (Dimensions), not to an instance.

Comment: Fixed. Thanks for the heads up